# Optimise Way to run youtube video on android

Tags: java, android

Can we have any optimise way to run video.Below mention is my code.This code help in run the youtube video.

```
if (YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayVideoIntent(activity)){
                            //Getting ID of YouTube video out of URL
                            List<NameValuePair> params = null;
                            try {
                                params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(sourceUrl), "UTF-8");

                            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String videoID = params.get(0).getValue();
                            Log.v(TAG, "YouTube Video ID:" + videoID);
                            // createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions only works for first
                            // video playback. Update to use stand-alone player api instead.

                            Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(
                                    activity, g.kGoogleAPIKey,
                                    videoID, 0, true, false);
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Video Playing in YouTube App....");                         
                        } else {
                            Log.v(TAG, "YouTube generic intent");
                            activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(sourceUrl)));
                            Log.i(TAG, "Video Playing in whatever user selected....");
                        }
```

Comment: Search on google there are lots of tutorials available....http://www.kpbird.com/2012/12/youtube-android-player-api-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

your question is a bit vague.. if all you want to do is play a youTube video from your app you can easily just call the yourtube intent.. and pass the url of the video as an extra.  this would open youTube..

alternatively you can get access to the youTube Player api: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary

which you will have to get an api key and do something like this:

**This example looks to see if the standalone player is available to your user and if it isn't calls youtube directly as stated in the first part of my answer**

```
  if (YouTubeIntents.canResolvePlayVideoIntent(activity)){
                            //Getting ID of YouTube video out of URL
                            List<NameValuePair> params = null;
                            try {
                                params = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(sourceUrl), "UTF-8");

                            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String videoID = params.get(0).getValue();
                            Log.v(TAG, "YouTube Video ID:" + videoID);
                            // createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions only works for first
                            // video playback. Update to use stand-alone player api instead.

                            Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(
                                    activity, g.kGoogleAPIKey,
                                    videoID, 0, true, false);
                            activity.startActivity(intent);
                            Log.i(TAG, "Video Playing in YouTube App....");                         
                        } else {
                            Log.v(TAG, "YouTube generic intent");
                            activity.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(sourceUrl)));
                            Log.i(TAG, "Video Playing in whatever user selected....");
                        }
```